# how to built news ticker in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have built a news ticker using CSS, but the transition doesn't seem to be smooth at all. I am having trouble figuring out how to get rid of the gap between the loops in my program. Can someone help me make the loop seamless?

Here is the code:

```css
.hwrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}

.hmove {
  display: flex;
}

.hitem {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes tickerh {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.hmove {
  animation: tickerh linear 5s infinite;
}

.hmove:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="hwrap">
  <div class="hmove">
    <div class="hitem">
      <p>"Imagination is more important than knowledge. For knowledge is limited, whereas imagination embraces the entire world, stimulating progress, giving birth to evolution."</p>
      <p>-Albert Einstein</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hitem">
      <p> "You may encounter many defeats, but you must not be defeated. In fact, it may be necessary to encounter the defeats so you can know who you are, what you can rise from, how you can still come out of it."</p>
      <p>-Maya Angelou</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hitem">
      <p>"Education is the most powerful weapon which you can use to change the world. It has the power to transform individuals, communities, and nations, creating a brighter and more equitable future for all."</p>
      <p>-Nelson Mandela</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hitem">
      <p> "The biggest adventure you can take is to live the life of your dreams. Don't be afraid to take risks, embrace your passions, and pursue what truly sets your soul on fire."</p>
      <p>-Oprah Winfrey</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hitem">
      <p>"Be the change that you wish to see in the world. Small acts of kindness and compassion can ripple through society, inspiring others to join the movement towards a more peaceful and just world."</p>
      <p>-Mahatma Gandhi</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hitem">
      <p> "Darkness cannot drive out darkness; only light can do that. Hate cannot drive out hate; only love can do that. Let us choose love over hate and strive for a world where justice and equality prevail."</p>
      <p>-Martin Luther King Jr.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, _specific_ question about your problem.

Comment: Does [this](https://codepen.io/lewismcarey/pen/GJZVoG) or [this](https://codepen.io/keith-greer/pen/wvwLEVq) help?

Comment: Have two copies of the text and animate to translateX(-50%)

Comment: So the issue is that it jumps at the end, instead of wrapping?